# "resource not provisioned in service stamp"

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

This error appears in the MARS of the server where the backup takes place. The Azure Backup Alert Service at no time sent us a copy failure notice, but for some reason we suddenly ignore the agent giving this error "resource not provisioned in service stamp" The Azure subscription data is: I send you a capture with the error provided by the agent and others with the data of the copy element.